# Get additional height from accordeon - jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I´ve got a dropdown function for a list of customers, onclick on a logo you the hidden content slides down to show additional content.

Now I have a accordeon in my hidden content and when I open the accordeon, the content below scrolls out of the div and you cant read it.

Is it possible, to chnage the height of the activ/shown divs "group" and "wrapper_hidden_content" on click of a accordeon element?

### JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/v5m4wyoo/2/

### JScode

```
//show hidden content function
 // global variables
                var nav1           = $('.group'),
                    navHeight1     = nav1.height(),
                    items1         = $('.group .partner_item .trigger'),
                    itemsSub1      = items1.next('.toggle_container'),
                    itemsSubOpen1  = false,
                    speed1         = 400;

                // global functions
                var navOpen1 = function (thisSubmenu1) {
                    itemsSubOpen1 = true;

                    // get height
                    thisSubmenu1.css('height', 'auto');
                    var thisHeight1 = thisSubmenu1.height();


                    thisSubmenu1
                        .css('height', '0')
                        .animate({height: thisHeight1 }, speed1)
                        .addClass('open')
                        .closest('.group')
                        .animate({height: thisHeight1 + navHeight1+130 }, speed1);
                };

                var navClose1 = function () {
                    itemsSubOpen1 = false;
                    items1.next('.open')
                        .animate({height: 0}, speed1)
                        .removeClass('open');
                    nav1.animate({height: navHeight1+125 }, speed1);
                };
                // prepare css
                itemsSub1.css('display', 'block');
                itemsSub1.css('height', '0');
                // click event
                items1.click(function(event) {

                    // set local variables
                    var thisItem1 = $(this),
                        thisSubmenu1 = thisItem1.next('.toggle_container');

                    // conditional click event handling
                    if ( itemsSubOpen1  ) {

                        if ( thisSubmenu1.hasClass('open') ) {
                            // only close
                            navClose1();
                        } else {
                            // close old, than open new
                            navClose1();
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                navOpen1(thisSubmenu1);
                            }, speed1);

                        }
                    } else {
                        // only open
                        navOpen1(thisSubmenu1);
                    }

                    // prevent default
                    event.preventDefault();

                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey the Answer is easy you just add   tog.parent().parent().parent().css('height','auto'); in your activate function that give the .toggle_container div height:auto so your function look like the following

```
 var activate = function(tog) {
    var tgs = $('div.toggler');
      if(!tog.hasClass('ui-state-active')){
       tog.removeClass('active');
       tog.parents('.group').css('padding-bottom',0);
      }else{
       tog.addClass('active');
          tog.parents('.group').eq(0).css('padding-bottom',tog.parent().parent().parent().height());
      } 
    tog.parent().parent().parent().css('height','auto');
    tgs.removeClass('active');
    tgs.next('div.accordion').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    tog.next('div.accordion').attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
  };
```

hope that help :D

Comment: Hi und thanks :)
That helps a little bit, but would it be possible, that the parent div "group" gets a padding-bottom with the same size of the toggle hight of the accordion?

Comment: try tog.parent().css('height',toggle.height()); this is the idea you have to change the selectors

Comment: let me understand you you need to give the parent div (droup) a padding

Comment: Yes the parent div (group) needs to get a padding-bottom with the value of the height of the accordion. So that it looks like the content pushes the content below, down.

Comment: No, its not really working, becouse every div (group) gets the padding-bottom and on click at the div (trigger) again, the padding-bottom needs to get the value of 0 again.
http://jsfiddle.net/v5m4wyoo/4/

Comment: Thats the problem, there are a few things the JS needs to do and thats more that I now about JS.

Comment: hope that what you need i edited the answer i cant chat with you i don't have a reputation you can help me by accept my answer thanks

Comment: Thanks, the problem is, that it jumps down but it should kind of slide down^^